# I want to be able to use a long value into a hh:mm:ss format from another class in a method in Java

Tags: java, time

Currently I have the total duration of time in a playlist, so i'm trying to use those long fields in song into a method in playlist into a format of HH:MM:SS.

Currently i'm working with this.

Playlist class

```java
public class Playlist
{
public double getTotalAmountOfDurationInAPlaylist()
            {
                long sum = 0;
                setTotalPlaylistTime(sum);
                    for (Song individualSong : getSongs())
                        {
                            sum = sum + individualSong.getSongDurationInSeconds() + individualSong.getSongDurationInMinutes() + individualSong.getSongDurationInHours();
                        }
                return sum;
            }
}
```

and in my Song class it's just private fields of long called songDurationInSeconds, songDurationInMinutes and songDurationInHours.
The Song class also includes all setters and getters for the fields.

Song class

```java
public class Song
{
        private long songDurationInSeconds;
        private long songDurationInMinutes;
        private long songDurationInHours;

        public Song(long songDurationInHours, long songDurationInMinutes, long songDurationInSeconds)
            {
                this.songDurationInHours = songDurationInHours;
                this.songDurationInMinutes = songDurationInMinutes;
                this.songDurationInSeconds = songDurationInSeconds;
            }
}
```

Hopefully this clarifies it, I've made a few adjustments since i'm still working on how to do it.

If further information is needed please let me know :)

Comment: Is the song duration double values denote Mins with secs as fractional part or Secs with millisecs?

Comment: So the song duration in double is the minutes then seconds so 1.5min is my double value which is 90 secs if that's what you were asking.

Comment: You should clarify in the question why type of values the duration can contain, preferable with an example with given input and expected output

Comment: Thank you for the feedback i'll make sure I clarify everything, i'll change it right now.

Comment: Interesting, you have completely redefined the question, why does `getTotalAmountOfDurationInAPlaylist` return a double when you work with long values and how on earth will you get anything useful out of that addition. 2 minutes + 45 seconds would equal 47 but 47 what?

Comment: I suggest that you replace your three `long` fields (instance variables) for song duration with just one `Duration` field/variable. `Duration` has methods `toHours`, `toMinutes` and `getSeconds` for when you want the duration in one of those units. And a `plus` method for adding up the durations of all the songs into a sum duration (total).

Comment: Is your declaration of the return value as a `double` a mistake? Did you mean `long`?

Comment: In my opinion this question should be closed until OP has decided how time should be represented and calculated.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## `java.time.Duration`

java.time is almost always where you want to go when you have time/date stuff to do.

```
java.time.Duration d = Duration.ofMillis((long) (1000L * sum));
```

then you can format that with a DateTimeFormatter from the j.t.format package as you want.

Comment: Does that mean i would have to put java.time.Duration d = Duration.ofMillis((long) (1000L * sum)); inside the foreach loop so that it converts the double into a long datatype value? and the datetimeformatter should be outside the foreach loop? Sorry i'm still a student in IT for java. Just asking for clarification.

Comment: Why not use [`Duration.ofSeconds`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html#ofSeconds(long)) and skip the math?

Comment: @BasilBourque There is absolutely no reason not to. `Duration.ofSeconds(sum)` is the simple, recommended and even the efficient way, even though the last doesn’t count. (Yes, you knew this already, but for everyone else reading along.)

Comment: ... because OP has a double and not a long. Read the question more carefully fellas :) @BasilBourque

Comment: The return value declaration of `double` looks like a mistake. All parts are `long` values as stated explicitly in the Question. A `long` is produced by the math. So it makes no sense to return a `double`.

Comment: @BasilBourque The math doesn't make sense anyway so it doesn't really matter if a long or a double is returned.

Answer (score 0):

This should solve your issue if you need it as String

```
        int s= (int) sum;
        System.out.println("Duration: "+String.format("%d:%02d:%02d", s / 3600, (s % 3600) / 60, (s % 60)));
```

OR
Use [Apache commons library](http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-3.0/org/apache/commons/lang3/time/DurationFormatUtils.html)

```
DurationFormatUtils.formatDuration(sum*1000l, "**H:mm:ss**", true);
```

Comment: The upper will generate an exception if the variable sum is of type double as OP specifies in the question. The value of minutes given in decimal format has to be multiplied by 60 and casted to int or long for this to work.

Comment: Not sure why this was upvoted when it deals with integer instead of double and the content of `sum` is most likely not what is expected here.

Comment: True, there was a need to cast to int first. It's been edited

Comment: No, then you loose information/precision. You need to work with double values.

Comment: After the latest update it looks like my comment about double is no longer valid but given the state of the question, neither is this answer.

Answer (score 0):

The [`java.time.Duration`](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.base/java/time/Duration.html) classes represents a span of time unattached to the timeline.

```
Duration duration = Duration.ZERO.plusHours( x ).plusMinutes( y ).plusSeconds( z ) ;
```

You can interrogate the `Duration` object for its entirety as a count of seconds.

```
long secondsTotal = duration.toSeconds() ;
```

I suggest you consider replacing your three `long` parts entirely. Just use `Duration` class as the type of your member field.

```
public class Song
{
        private String title ;
        private Duration duration ;

        public Song( final Duration d )
            {
                Objects.requiresNonNull( d ) ;
                this.duration = d ; 
            }

        public Song(long songDurationInHours, long songDurationInMinutes, long songDurationInSeconds)
            {
                // … check for valid data, no nulls, appropriate range of values.
                Duration d = Duration.ZERO.plusHours( songDurationInHours ).plusMinutes( songDurationInMinutes ).plusSeconds( songDurationInSeconds ) ;
                this.duration = d ;
            }
}
```

By the way, that kind of class would be better defined as a `record` in Java 16 and later.

Your playlist class might look like this.

```java
public class Playlist
{
    private List < Song > songs ;

public Duration getDuration()
            {
                    Duration total = Duratiin.ZERO ;
                    for (Song song : this.songs )
                        {
                              total = total.plus( song.getDuration() ) ;
                         }
                     return total ; 
            }
}
```

I also suggest avoiding the use of clock-style time to represent a span. The [ISO 8601 standard defined a textual format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_8601#Durations) that is not easily mistaken for time-of-day.

The `Duration` class generates and parses text by default in this standard format.